# webrtc streaming in windows is slow

Tags: windows, webrtc

We are using webrtc to share a remote windows machine desktop. Even when the remote machine has a high bandwidth link upto 2.5MBps and the max bitrate configured in the SDP is 1MBps, the stream couldn't take more than 50KBps resulting in bad quality/jerky stream.
On a similar setup with Mac as a remote host, we are getting a throughput of upto 250KBps on the local system, which results in a smooth stream.
After some analysis we found that it's neither an issue with Network, because the windows machine is able to perform other network tasks with full bandwidth, nor is it related to local network or latency(since the mac as a remote peer is giving better results) 
The webrtc  in windows is somehow writing to the network stack slower as compared to the mac, the FPS captured is 28 but the FPS sent falls down to 4 to 10 and remains there for a good amount of time. Is this something known? Am I doing something wrong? Do we have any hacks to tweak the network processing for windows? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a native application? Or in a browser?

Comment: What does CPU utilization look like on that windows machine? Is this in Chrome(if so, what does chrome://webrtc-internals/ say)?

Comment: Its chromium browser. CPU utilization is around 50%-70%. What exactly should I look for in webrtc-internals?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with Google release versions of Chrome / Chromium. Unless, maybe if you building Chrome / Chromium from source and running it in there? If that is the case, then I've had success with Android-Browser connections by playing around with the bit-rate, packet drop and a few other settings / logic in WebRTC. I do not remember the exact variables or files, but you might be able to get there by searching WebRTC for leaky buckets (not necessarily that exact phrase.